# Spring Kafka Admin Client multiple bootstrap servers Kafka with security (jass_config)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

How Do I connect to multiple bootstrap servers(DEV, STAGE and PROD) from a microservice ( Admin MS) with security in place?
I want to connect to all the kafka servers and create/manage topics, create ACLS etc.
I am using spring kafka adminclient , and configuring properties from application.yml using spring boot to connect to Dev right now. But now I want to connect to all environments.
Is there an easier and better approach other that wring a properties hashmap and putting config values in it. Does Spring cloud stream help? 
Is this something similar to connecting multiple databases to a micro service ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating multiple child boot applications, each with its own environment containing the properties.

But it's probably easier to bypass Boot's auto configuration and wire up your own `AdminClient`s with their own properties.